# Lazy property for http get request

Tags: rxjs, angular2-services, angular-observable

I would like to create a lazy property in a service, meaning - I would like to have a (lets say) boolean member which should be initialized by a get request.
The property checks whether the member is already initialized:
1. If so - it returns the value or an observable of the value.
2. If not - the get request is executed, the member is being initialed and then the value (or an observable) is being rerturned.
this.getIsTrue is an http get request.
See my code in the service:

```
isTrue: boolean = null;
get IsTrue() : Observable<boolean> // It can return even boolean and not 
                                       observablle
{
    if (this.isTrue!= null)  
    {
       return of(this.ifTrue); // can return even boolean and not 
                                  observablle 
    }
    else
    {
      this.getIsTrue().subscribe(result => { 
      this.isTrue = result;
      return of(this.isTrue);});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tap` if you need to make side-effects instead of subscribing to it:

```
return this.getIsTrue().pipe(
  tap(result => this.isTrue = result),
);
```